# how to display a circle next to columns header in j query data-table

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a jquery data-table where i need to display a small colored circle next to each column header name as shown below[image]

Want to add a small blue circle only on the header

I am defining the header columns as shown below

```
  var popupDataColumns = [
            {
                "data": "Occurrence",
                "title": "Occurrence"
            },
            { data: "Release", title: "Release" },
            { data: "SWID", title: "SWID" },
            { data: "Event", title: "Event" },
            { data: "Level", title: "Level" },
            { data: "ReleaseSWID", title: "ReleaseSWID" },
        ];
```

Please let me know how can i achieve it

Comment: Maybe, you could make use of the `::after` pseudo element.

Comment: what kind of circle you need, if you need all same kind of then use : before , : after

Comment: can u please point me to a sample

Answer (score 0):

Added svg circles in th

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({


            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name<svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg></th>
            <th>Position
                <svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg>
            </th>
            <th>Office
                <svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg>
            </th>
            <th>Age
                <svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg>
            </th>
            <th>Start date
                <svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg>
            </th>
            <th>Salary
                <svg height="10" width="10" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
                </svg>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use FontAwesome, which would make it very easy to add other kind of graphics to the headers later on. Simply define a class like this:

```css
.circle::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f111";
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Note that if you are using Font Awesome 5, the fontname should be "Font Awesome 5 Free" (among other possible font names, google the details). Then you can colorize the circles by adding CSS classes like this :

```css
.circle.red::after {
  color: red;
}
.circle.blue::after {
  color: blue;
}
.circle.green::after {
  color: green;
}
```

And when you need to add circles to any header, use the API:

```js
table.columns(1).header().to$().addClass('circle red')
table.columns(2).header().to$().addClass('circle blue')
table.columns(3).header().to$().addClass('circle green')
```

Should look like this :

[image]

here is a demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/aho825q3/**

Answer (score 0):

you can use Font Awesome for display circle after title.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"], 
   
   
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];
  
  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "ExamCount <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }, {
    title: "L1 <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }, {
    title: "L2 <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }, {
    title: "L3 <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }, {
    title: "L4 <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }, {
    title: "StandardFun.. <i class='fa fa-circle-thin' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
    dom: 'Bfrtip', // Needs button container
    select: 'single',
    responsive: true,
    altEditor: true, // Enable altEditor
    buttons: []
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example" style="width:100%">

    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```